# Gulp: Passing through to a stream depending on the contents of a stream

Tags: node.js, stream, streaming, gulp

I have the following simplified gulp task:

```
gulp.src(...)
    .pipe(stuff())
    .pipe(moreStuff())
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(yetMoreStuff());
```

I only want the `imagemin` stream to be called when the file path contains "xyz", but I want the other three streams to always be called.

Called `gulp.src()` in another place is not appropriate—this example is massively simplified, and duplicating everything would be messy as hell.

So far, I've got this far:

```
var through = require('through2');

gulp.src(...)
    .pipe(stuff())
    .pipe(moreStuff())
    .pipe(through.obj(function (file, enc, cb) {
          console.log(file.path.indexOf('hero') !== -1);

          // file has a pipe method but what do I do?!
        }))
    .pipe(yetMoreStuff());
```

Doesn't do anything. I don't know vinyl / streams well enough to be able to do this by myself :(

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like [gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-filter) might be what you're looking for.

```
var Filter = require('gulp-filter');
var filter = Filter(['**xyz**']);

gulp.src(...)
    .pipe(stuff())
    .pipe(moreStuff())
    .pipe(filter)
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(filter.restore())
    .pipe(yetMoreStuff());
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Ended up using [gulp-if](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if) instead because I want an else condition, but I didn't put that in the question :)